# Can F5 work as both webserver as well as load balancer

Tags: apache, webserver, load, load-balancing, f5

I have a fair bit of understanding of the webserver namely apache httpd. We have a web component which is is build in Angular, HTML5, CSS3.
We deploy the UI compoenent in apache httpd 2.4.

Recently someone proposed to replace this with F5 load balancer.

Is it possible to replace webserver with load balancer ?
Can we deploy the html components in F5 load balancer ?

My understanding is that load balancer helps in clustering the webservers based on different algorithms like Round robin, Weighted round robin, Least Connection etc and cannot indpendently the server the requests coming from end user.

Answer (score 1):

You can build out basic web functionality in iRules, but if you need more than something like a static or slighting dynamic maintenance page or serving a proxy pac file I'd recommend against it.

[Maintenance Page](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/irules-recipe-4-static-maintenance-page-23131).
[Serving a Proxy Pac file](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/pacfiles-r-irules)

I need to clean up the formatting of the second link, but you'll get the idea.